# get all sequencer strips in python

Tags: python, scripting, blender-internal-render-engine, video-sequence-editor

Hello all blenderheads ! 
i'm trying to make a little script to collect then relink all sequencer strip in a blend file, i'm currently getting something, but only in the active scene, i can't get it work in all scenes in the blend.
Here what i've got so far :
(sorry it the code isn't so good, im a newbie in python :))

```
import bpy
import os
import shutil

### make all path absolute ###
bpy.ops.file.make_paths_absolute()

### get the blendfile path ###
blendossier=bpy.path.abspath("//")
blendnom=bpy.path.abspath(bpy.path.basename(bpy.context.blend_data.filepath))

### set the new folder accordingly to blendfile path ###
ressourcesfolder=blendossier + "/" + blendnom + "___ressources"

### create the folder ###
os.makedirs(ressourcesfolder, exist_ok=True)

### get context scene name ###
scname = bpy.context.scene.name

### get all strips in the scene ###
strip = bpy.data.scenes[scname].sequence_editor.sequences_all

### copy strips ###

for obj in strip:
    ### set a specific folder ###
    folder=ressourcesfolder + "/" + "Video Sequencer"

    ### check if file isn't already in it ###
    if bpy.path.abspath(obj.filepath) != folder + "/" + bpy.path.basename(obj.filepath):

        ### create the folder ###
        os.makedirs(folder, exist_ok=True)
        ### copy the file ###
        shutil.copy2(bpy.path.abspath(obj.filepath), folder + "/" + bpy.path.basename(obj.filepath)) 
        ### get the new path ###
        newpath=folder + "/" + bpy.path.basename(obj.filepath)
        ### relink the strip to new path ###
        obj.filepath=newpath


### make all path relative ###
bpy.ops.file.make_paths_relative()
```

does anyone have an idea ? i'm stuck with that... thank you !

Comment: You are getting scene name from the context scene.  For all in blend file use `for scene in bpy.data.scenes:`  `strip = scene.sequence_editor...`  etc.

Comment: Also, might want to test if a sequence editor exist in the scene.

Comment: and @cmomoney, if there's no video sequence in the scene, there's no error message, i think thanks to the "for obj in strip:", if there's no obj, it's not a problem ?

Comment: @cmomoney my bad, you were absolutely right ! just added [if scene.sequence_editor is not None:] to the script to get it works even if there wasn't one ! thanks for the remark !

Comment: @tonton You should post the answer below ;-)

Comment: yep , it's done :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hey thanks to batfinger and cmomoney, here's the answer :

```
### Strips ###
for scene in bpy.data.scenes: 

    if scene.sequence_editor is not None:

        strip = scene.sequence_editor.sequences_all

        if strip is not None:
```

works perfectly to get all the strip in the sequencer editor in any scene of your blend file ! hope it'll help for people in same situation !